# How to update ListView's selected item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView which displays multiple rows of ListViewItems. The user is able to edit one of these items through a dialog which opens after clicking 'Edit.' When the dialog closes I would like to modify the selected ListViewItem such that it reflects the new settings.

Here is how I currently update my item:

```
private void btnEditSnmpV3Setting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem selectedItem = lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedItems[0];
        NetworkDiscoverySnmpSetting settings = (NetworkDiscoverySnmpSetting)selectedItem.Tag;
        NetworkDiscoverySnmpV3SettingsDialog dialog = new NetworkDiscoverySnmpV3SettingsDialog(settings);

        //Pass in the owner for centering of dialog.
        if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedItem.SubItems.Clear();
            selectedItem.Text = settings.SnmpV3Username;
            selectedItem.SubItems.Add(settings.SecurityMode.ToString());
            selectedItem.SubItems.Add(settings.AuthenticationProtocol.ToString());
            selectedItem.SubItems.Add(settings.PrivacyProtocol.ToString());
            selectedItem.Tag = settings;
        }
    }
}
```

I found this to be a poor solution due to the fact that I need to touch code in multiple places if my ListView's number of columns changes.

I handled  this code-reuse issue during the 'Add' event (as opposed to 'Edit') by giving `NetworkDiscoverySnmpSetting` a utility method:

```
public ListViewItem ToListViewItem()
{
    ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
    listViewItem.Text = SnmpV3Username;
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(SecurityMode.ToString());
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(AuthenticationProtocol.ToString());
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(PrivacyProtocol.ToString());
    listViewItem.Tag = this;
    return listViewItem;
}
```

which is used like so:

```
private void btnAddSnmpV3Setting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkDiscoverySnmpSetting settings = new NetworkDiscoverySnmpSetting(NetworkDiscovery.ID);
    NetworkDiscoverySnmpV3SettingsDialog dialog = new NetworkDiscoverySnmpV3SettingsDialog(settings);
    //Pass in the owner for centering of dialog.
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        lstVwSNMPv3Settings.Items.Add(settings.ToListViewItem());
}
```

Unfortunately, ListView.SelectedItems does not allow collection-modification. As such, this does not compile:

```
lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedItems[0] = settings.ToListViewItem();
```

How should I change my first code-snippet so that I do not need to update my code in multiple places when ListView's columns change?

Comment: Do yourself a HUGE favour and google and learn about ObjectListView. It's, in 1 word, AWESOME.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can modify the element itself rather than replacing it with another one, because ListViewItem is a class, so it's a reference type.

In order to do this follow these steps:

- get currently selected item and save it to variable like this: `ListViewItem selectedItem = lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedItems[0];`
- modify your `ToListViewItem` method to `void ToListViewItem(ListViewItem listViewItem)` (return void and take `ListViewItem` object as parameter and modify it instead of creating a new object. It should also rather modify properties of existing subitems than creating new ones. It can look more or less like this:

  ```
  public void ToListViewItem(ListViewItem listViewItem)
  {
      listViewItem.Text = SnmpV3Username;
      listViewItem.SubItems[0].Text = SecurityMode.ToString();
      listViewItem.SubItems[1].Text = AuthenticationProtocol.ToString();
      listViewItem.SubItems[2].Text = PrivacyProtocol.ToString();
      listViewItem.Tag = this;
  }
  ```
- call `ToListViewItem(selectedItem);`
- you don't have to assign the modified item back to the collection, because you use a reference, which means you've just modify the same object that's in the `ListView`

I did a quick test and the method seems to modify texts of existing items without issues.

Comment: I modified your method back to basically what my original one was, but used your idea. For future reference -- setting the Text property of a ListViewItem has the side-effect of adding an element to the SubItems array. That was why I was calling Clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

`ListViewItem`s have a `bool Selected` property that you can toggle to make them selected or not selected.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution, that worked for me:

```
lstVwSNMPv3Settings.Items[lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedIndices[0]] = myNewItem;
```

But be careful to first make sure there is an item selected:

```
if (lstVwSNMPv3Settings.SelectedIndices.Count > 0) { ... }
```